# SQL: selecting 5 urls, with least visited domains as fast as possible

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `url_stack` table with `urlid` and `domainid` and a `domain_stack` table with `domainid` and `domain_count`.

`url_stack` has `urlid` as its primary key and a `BTREE` index on `domainid`. `domain_stack` has `domainid` as its primary and a `BTREE` index on `domain_count`.

I constantly add urls to the stack. When popping a url from the stack, I add `1` to its `domain_count`.

When I pop a url, I keep the count of its domain, this why there are many domains doesn't have any url (this is why @moj answer is faulty).

When popping I would like to select a `url` for each of the available `domain_counts` and limit myself to the top 5.

for example, a common result would be:

```
+------------+------------+--------------+
| urlid      | domainid   | domain_count |
+------------+------------+--------------+
|  852336945 | -184315873 |            1 |
| 1930023009 |  -43391685 |            2 |
| -112137768 | 1607144692 |            4 |
| 1673460622 |  567460239 |            8 |
|  612511843 | 1444323871 |           11 |
+------------+------------+--------------+  
5 rows in set (5.37 sec)
```

By invoking:

```
SELECT urlid,domain_stack.domainid,domain_stack.domain_count
FROM  domain_stack
INNER JOIN url_stack
ON url_stack.domainid = domain_stack.domainid
GROUP BY domain_stack.domain_count LIMIT 5;
```

The problem is this is way too slow - I have to get under a 0.5 second per query. How should I change my query / my tables to make this faster?

*EDIT*: here's a link describing the situation http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70ded/1/0

Comment: Can you explain the use of `GROUP BY`? Or it's a typo? Have you tried `ORDER BY domain_stack.domain_count ASC LIMIT 5;` for your last line?

Comment: @ace there could be many urls with `domain_count` 1, if I used `ORDER BY` I would get 5 urls with `domain_count = 1`, but I want one of each domain_count category, I hope this explains it..

Comment: ah. so if I have 5 urls with `domain_count = 1`, you only get 1 url and it doesn`t matter which one you get?

Comment: @ace - correct! and this is why I believe this can be done faster, I have to discard the extra items with the same url_count during the join, but I have no clue how. I've added a link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70ded/1/0

Comment: @zenpoy - Have you seen the last comment to my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (group values of domain_count before join):

```
select 
    us.*, -- random row from group is ok
    top5.domain_count 
from 
    url_stack us
    inner join 
         (  
           select 
               domainid, -- random domain id from group is ok
               domain_count
           from 
               domain_stack
           group by 
               domain_count asc
           limit 5 -- all domains must have a counter > 0
         ) top5
         on top5.domainid = us.domainid
group by
    top5.domain_count asc
limit 5
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70ded/55/0)

Comment: This looks good at first, but since in fact there are domains in `domain_stack` that doesn't have url refering to them, the query you wrote returns empty set...

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood the semantics of your data model correctly.
It might help, if you extend your example, so that the issue you described becomes visible.

What about the following selection at the inner query:
_where domain_count > 0_